# Why does SASS compiler adds [dir] at the beginning?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am trying to compile Bootstrap 5.3 along with custom SASS files.

This is what I have

```scss
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

@import 'other/file.scss';

[data-bs-theme=light] .bg-default {
    background-color: rgba(var(--bs-light-rgb), var(--bs-bg-opacity)) !important;
}
```

Oddily, last section generates the following CSS

```css
[dir] [data-bs-theme=light] .bg-default {
  background-color: rgba(var(--bs-light-rgb), var(--bs-bg-opacity)) !important;
}
```

I expected see the following CSS instead

```css
[data-bs-theme=light] .bg-default {
  background-color: rgba(var(--bs-light-rgb), var(--bs-bg-opacity)) !important;
}
```

It adds `[dir]` at the beginning. Why does it add `[dir]`? How can I prevent it from adding `[dir]` directive?

Having the `[dir]` seems to be preventing me from using the custom class. For example

```
<div class="bg-default">Hello world!</div>
```

does not change the color of the divider.

**UPDATED**

When `background-color` is used the `[dir]` seems to be added.

```
[data-bs-theme=light] {
    .bg-default {
        background-color: rgba(248, 249, 250, 1);
    }

    .text-bg-default {
        color: var(--bs-body-color);
        background-color: rgba(248, 249, 250, 1);
    }
}
```

The generated CSS looks like this

```
[dir] [data-bs-theme=light] .bg-default {
  background-color: rgb(248, 249, 250);
}
[data-bs-theme=light] .text-bg-default {
  color: var(--bs-body-color);
}

[dir] [data-bs-theme=light] .text-bg-default {
  background-color: rgb(248, 249, 250);
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue on SassMeister. What compiler do you use? Does it happen if you remove the `@import`?

Comment: I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-dart-sass with gulp. It happens even if I remove the `@import` it seems I tried to compile this it still added it 
`
[data-bs-theme=light] .bg-default {
    background-color: rgba(var(--bs-light-rgb), var(--bs-bg-opacity)) !important;
}
`

Comment: Their docs talk about it [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/rtl/) a little. Something to do with RTLCSS postprocessor?

Comment: @Ouroborus thank you. I don't see where `[dir]` is explained on that docs link.

Comment: What config do you use for gulp?

Comment: @Arkellys I use `scss({precision: 10,})` when compiling sass.

Comment: @Jay It's in the part about RTL. The whole thing is related to reading left-to-right or right-to-left, depending on language. You can [read more about the attribute here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much more digging, I found out the cause. My gulpfile.js uses `gulp-postcss` which adds the `[dir]` directive like this `postcss([rtl()])`.

Removing that stopped this behavior.